# VS Code Ctrl+ click Search in Specific folder

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a source code in JavaScript. It is a collection of around 200 files which aren't  segregated into modules,

The project files are bundled during the build step.

Some of the 200 files have imports which were very long `../../../../../folder1/file1`
To make these import length smaller we devised a method to replace it with `folder1/file1`

Now during our build step we simply add the `../../../../`
All this works fine and the build step succeeds properly. The problem comes in the development mode when I try to do a ctrl + click on any import statement, since it does not know where to look for the file.

Is there a way in VS code setting or extension to add additional places to look at when we do a ctrl + click.

Comment: you can write your own extension to do this, by removing the `../` you loose the intellisense

Comment: @rioV8 isnt there a way to tweak the intellisense?